# I need to find IC marked ID9MU

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I can't find this IC in the red box
[image: ID9MU]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [MPS MP1540](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP1540/document_id/11344/) step-up converter. The actual marking is `D9MU`, the "I" is the pin 1 indicator.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [szlcsc.com](https://item.szlcsc.com/15709.html))